# Custom Capacitor Plugin - add Android dependencies

Tags: java, android, ionic-framework, capacitor

How can I add an Android build dependency to my custom capacitor plugin for app rate based on

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review/kotlin-java#java

It fails the build with not finding `com.google.android.play.core` so I wonder how can I add it as a dependency to the component build?
Below is the error

```
/AppRate.java:9: error: package com.google.android.play.core.review does not exist
import com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo;
                                          ^
/AppRate.java:10: error: package com.google.android.play.core.review does not exist
import com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager;
                                          ^
/AppRate.java:11: error: package com.google.android.play.core.review does not exist
import com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory;
                                          ^
/AppRate.java:12: error: package com.google.android.play.core.tasks does not exist
import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.Task;
                                         ^
/AppRate.java:17: error: class AppRate clashes with package of same name
public class AppRate extends Plugin {

       ^
/AppRate/BuildConfig.java:4: error: package me.url.AppRate clashes with class of same name
package me.url.AppRate;
^
/AppRate.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
        Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();
```

I am also not sure about the clash error, but that is a separate topic I guess.

Note - I tried integrating the ionic native plugins but had weird build issues. iOS now works with my custom plugin, fixing Android now.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2"
```

to my `build.grade` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps to see:

1. Delete the Buildconfig.java
2. Refactor -> Rename, error class.
3. Build -> Rebuild Project!
   --

And if not, share what you have in the file: build.gradle in the **defaultConfig** section and AndroidManifest from the **manifest** section.